# AWS API Gateway: form-data support

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

Is it possible to send request with: **Content-Type: multipart/form-data** to API Gateway?

In my case, I try to send form-data like below via Postman:

```
user[email]:extest829@ex.com
user[password]:password
user[password_confirmation]:password
user[username]:testUser
```

But It seems that API Gateway loses the content.

Everything works fine when I send it as: **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** or **application/json**.

Comment: Solved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255249/7745796

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using **mulipart/form-data** is not fully supported by AWS API Gateway, especially when we try to send file via mulipart/form-data.

To send image along with other data from form, probably the best solution would be send it as JSON, where image is encoded with base64.

For example, when someone want to send:

1. Username (string)
2. Avatar (image)

Avatar should be encoded with base64. It gives an image as a text, like:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyA...
```

The content of POST message would be:

```
{
    "user_account": {
           "avatar": "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyA...",
           "username": "my name"
    }
}
```

**API Gateway**

In API Gateway, under your API, open **Models** and create new model, for example **UserAccount**:

```
{
   "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title": "UserAccountUpdate",
   "type": "object",
   "properties": {
   "user": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
          "avatar": { "type": "string" },
          "username": { "type": "string" }
     }
   }
  }
}
```

In **Method Request** -> **HTTP Request Headers** set: `Content-Type`.

In **Method Request** -> **Request Body** set: `application/json` and as model use created **UserAccount** model.

In **Integration Request** -> **Content Handling** set as: Passthrough.

In **Integration Request** -> **Body Mapping Templates** choose: *When no template matches the reuqest Content-Type header*. (You can also use two other options here and set additional mapping templates).

**Backend**

Backend receives an image as a text encoded with base64. So probably before it uses futher, it needs to decode it from text to image.

Encoding/decoding images with base64 is quite popular, so you should find some appropriate tools / libs in your frameworks.

Comment: hey, @nicq is it still not supported? Is it the best solution?

Comment: @nicq Thanks mate. Your provided solution really helped and made my day.

Comment: The Api Gateway does now support multipart/form-data, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60509051/aws-upload-csv-file-using-api-gateway-using-multipart-form-data as an example of the required changes. The main thing to keep in mind is to allow the gateway to accept binary media types.

Answer (score 1):

When you are sending request with **Content-Type: multipart/form-data to API Gateway**, you need to pass through your original **Content-Type** header to your integration endpoint.

```
aws apigateway update-integration \
     --rest-api-id a1b2c3d4e5 \
     --resource-id a1b2c3 \
     --http-method POST \
     --patch-operations op='replace',path='/requestParameters/integration.request.header.Content-Type',value='method.request.header.Content-Type'
```

Answer (score -1):

Code example for managing binary data in AWS Gateway and Proxy+ Lambda. Or to upload and retrieve files from servers using AWS Gateway and Proxy Lambda+
[Click here](https://pretham-shreyas.medium.com/image-upload-and-retrieval-from-server-using-aws-api-gateway-proxy-and-lambda-91f6d176c15)