# AWS - Upload CSV file using API Gateway using multipart/form-data

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I have a use-case where I need to upload the CSV file by using AngularJS App through AWS API Gateway, to my backend application (running in Elastic Beanstalk - Django Python REST App).

1. The API Gateway is integrated with AWS Cognito.
2. The backend application expects the form-data with CSV uploads.

I have created API Gateway with a resource like /main_resource/upload_csv with the POST method.

Currently, I am testing this with sample Javascript application that makes an AJAX call to the API Gateway URL. Below is the AJAX call

`$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://47483nvh39.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mystage/main_resource/upload_csv',
    headers: {
        Authorization: authToken,
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
    },
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    success: completeRequest,
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ', textStatus, ', Details: ', errorThrown);
        console.error('Response: ', jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log("Status: " + jqXHR.status);
        if (jqXHR.status == 401 || jqXHR.status == 403) {
            //redirectToLogin();
        } else {
            alert('An error occured:\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});`

Important settings are done in API Gateway resource POST method

1. API Gateway -> Settings -> Binary Media Types - added 'multipart/form-data
2. Added headers to "Method Request" - "Content-Type" and "Accept"
3. Added headers to "Integration Request" - "Content-Type" and "Accept"
4. Added Content type to "Method Request" Request Body as "multipart/form-data"
5. In "Integration Request" added multipart/form-data to "Mapping Templates"

After doing all these settings I am getting response as 500 "Internal server error".
I have gone through the logs of the Django app and found that the backend URL is not getting accessed.

Any help related to this is appreciated

Thanks

Avinash Deshmukh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am finally able to perform the `POST` request with `multipart/form-data` for CSV uploads.

Below are the required steps.

1. Add the binary media type in API Gateway -> Settings -> Binary Media Types 'multipart/form-data'
2. Add the headers "Content-Type" and "Accept" into "Method Request".
3. Add the "Content-Type" to "Method Request" -> Request Body as "multipart/form-data".
4. **In "Integration Request" select the checkbox "Use Proxy Integration".**

In the Ajax call remove the "Content-Type" from the headers list. It is observed that the "Content-Type" header is sent with the "Request Body" payload.
So the modified Ajax call can be something like this:

`$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://47483nvh39.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/mystage/main_resource/upload_csv',
    headers: {
        Authorization: authToken,
        "Accept": "*/*"
    },
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data',
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    processData: false,
    success: completeRequest,
    error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error: ', textStatus, ', Details: ', errorThrown);
        console.error('Response: ', jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log("Status: " + jqXHR.status);
        if (jqXHR.status == 401 || jqXHR.status == 403) {
            //redirectToLogin();
        } else {
            alert('An error occured:\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    }
});`

Hope this will help those who are facing the challenges during the integration.